# Why does this decryption not return the correct value

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with a column, SSN, and an empty one, SSNEncrypted Varbinary(MAX). I do this:

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SSNKey
    DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE SSNCert;

UPDATE [dbo].[Customers]
    SET [SSNEncrypted] = EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('SSNKey'), [dbo].[Customers].ssn);

CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SSNKey;
```

I can confirm the ssn column contains a value '3xx-xx-xxxx'. But when I do the following:

```
   OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SSNKey
    DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE SSNCert;

SELECT 
     CONVERT(VARCHAR, DecryptByKey( [SSNEncrypted]) ) as SSN_decrypted
  FROM [dbo].[Customers]

CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SSNKey;
```

I get a value of 3. I think it's giving me just the first number. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What are the data types of the `ssn` and `SSNEncrypted` columns?

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this. Tell me the exact `snn` column type and give me one real `ssn` value (it may be fake, but with which there is issue).

Comment: So for some reason, it works when I change the SET clause to `SET [SSNEncrypted] = EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('SSNKey'), CONVERT(VARBINARY, [dbo].[Customers].ssn));`

Comment: Data types are VARBINARY(MAX) and VARCHAR(12)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use nvarchar(max) in your decryption convertion

**OLD:**

```sql
SELECT 
     CONVERT(VARCHAR, DecryptByKey( [SSNEncrypted]) ) as SSN_decrypted
  FROM [dbo].[Customers]
```

**NEW:**

```sql
SELECT 
     CONVERT(nvarchar(max), DecryptByKey( [SSNEncrypted]) ) as SSN_decrypted
  FROM [dbo].[Customers]
```

Worked for me!